# Google 404 Errors

Tags: 404-error, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

It seems Google Tries to crawl pages I never created and gets a 404 error, but it thinks or maybe somewhere in my code, google thinks there is a second page.

For example, I have this page
http://ecsimplified.com/portfolio_category/tops

But not this page that google found a 404 error:
//ecsimplified.com/portfolio_category/tops/page/2/

Since I didn't create this page or link to this page, why would it find this error?

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by a small bug in my first implementation of the [rel="next" and rel="prev" features](http://yoast.com/rel-next-prev-paginated-archives/) that [Google launched 2 weeks ago](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html) in my WordPress SEO plugin. That bug has been fixed, you're up to date and the 404's should go away soon enough, nothing to worry about!

Comment: Can you be sure I'm up to date? Google dropped me from page 2 to 14 after finding these errors and it's reduced our sales down from being able to pay rent to almost nothing!

Comment: That's not due to just one 404, seriously.

Comment: Right, that was just an example. google webmaster tools says it finds multiple crawl error pages that I have no idea where the link is coming from. For example, it says some category page links to page 2 of that category, but I don't see it on the page or source, but I'm not the expert you are. By the way, I'm honored to get a comment from you. ;) Our little site is http://ecsimplified.com

Comment: In the Webmaster Tools, the updates as of today are still showing crawl errors (assuming from the Yoast SEO plugin) that show page/2 or page/# from a category. How can I get this looked into - is there a Yoast SEO Reviews page?

Comment: Any solutions yet? This problem is still here. Using 1.2.7. I also get 404 on pages i never created.